# Backbone - simple collection view - can't print items

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views

This is a really simple problem. I'm trying to print out each instance of the Student Model in the Collection. There's one line in the `printData` function: `this.$el.append(model_view.el);` where I think I'm missing something. Full JSFiddle example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bengrunfeld/vy7vnuet/).

```
// Model
var Student = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        name: '',
        age: '',
        major: '',
    }
});

// Collection
ExampleCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Student
});

// Model View
var ModelView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('.example-content'),
    template: _.template( $('#example-target').html() ),

    render: function(){
        var studentTemplate = this.template(this.model.toJSON());
        this.$el.html(studentTemplate);
    }
});

// Collection View
var CollectionView = Backbone.View.extend({
    render: function(){
        this.collection.each(this.printData, this);
        return this;
    },
    printData: function(target){
        var model_view = new ModelView({ model: target });
        this.$el.append(model_view.el);
    }
});

var matt = new Student({name: 'Matt', age: 32, major: 'French'});
var nick = new Student({name: 'Nick', age: 27, major: 'Science'});
var ellen = new Student({name: 'Ellen', age: 63, major: 'Geriatrics'});

var studentList = new ExampleCollection([matt, nick, ellen]);

var collection_view = new CollectionView({ collection: studentList });
collection_view.render();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your `CollectionView` doesn't have an 'el' specified, so you shouldn't be trying to append anything to it.  Your `ModelView`s are putting themselves on the page, you don't need to do anything else to them.

Now then, you have a syntax error:  Take off the `.el` in that line you specified.  In fact, the easiest way to fix that line is to simply call `render()` on each of the Students in your collection and stop trying to append them to something.

I believe you are trying to show all of the items, not just one, so each of the items should be appending themselves to their parent element...  Call `.append(studentTemplate)`, not `.html(studentTemplate)`.

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vy7vnuet/9/)